# Can I resume make after a Ctrl+C?

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make, kill

I am installing gcc version 5.1 on a supercomputer cluster. I configured it and am now running the make command. It has been several hours and is still running as it is a long install, but the work day is now over and I have to leave. If I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to quit the make, if I re-run make tomorrow morning will it resume where it left off? Or will it have to start over again? Will this cause problems or errors if I interrupt the make?

Comment: Yes, you can. That's what make is for -- finished stuff doesn't get recompiled if it doesn't need to be.

Comment: I'd leave it on over the night, though.

Comment: that depends on the rules in the Makefile(s)

Comment: Some of the jobs that make launches might not be happy. For the future might be a good idea to launch the make in a `screen` or a `vnc` session which allow you to disconnect without affecting the make job and re-connect later on (maybe even from another computer, say from home later on). This way make can continue its work and you don't have to re-run it to get the job done.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the process (technically, the process group) that is running in your terminal is killed. You can't resurrect it. All you can do is run it again.

Running `make` involves a lot of steps that each compile a single file, or link some files, or run one test, etc. When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the current step is cancelled, but the data from all the previous steps is still there. The make utility is designed to quickly find out what steps have already been performed and don't need to be performed again. So if you just run `make` again, it will analyze the situation for a short time (maybe a few seconds for a large projects) and resume where it left off.

If the machine isn't rebooted over night, you can keep commands running on it, even if you log out for the night. Start a terminal multiplexer such as [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) or [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux). For example, from a terminal, run

```
screen
```

This opens a new shell in your terminal. Here, switch to the relevant directory and type `make`. Then detach from the screen session by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>. You're back to your original shell prompt, but the command inside screen is still running. You can log out, log back in, and reattach to the still-running screen session by running

```
screen -rd
```

Comment: make checks if atime or mtime of output is newer than inputs. I am not sure if in proposed scenario gcc is intwrrupted it ctrl+c in middle of writting to file what happens : if file is not written ? Or left in half and make assume it's competed because of a/mtime ? Etc...

Comment: The output file will be partially written, but make has a protection for that: it has a handler for Ctrl+C that deletes the target of the current rule.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't know about that :D

Comment: Thanks for all the answers guys, I appreciate the help! Came back the next day and just re-ran make, it resumed where it left off and successfully compiled.